# Is there a way to produce a plot of ranges using scattergraphs in ggplot 2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make plots scatter-graph to represent maximum and minimum x and y values for various sources
E.g. `Algae= d13` has  `-5 >= C >= -10` and  `5 <= C/N <= 9`.

As shown in the image the plots form a box but I need to filter out the sources to construct lines between them separately. I tried using the filter function but had no luck, I've only been using R for a week or so...

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qcrP.png)

[eg graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kh3XO.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be helpful if you could make a minimal reproducible example that others can run other their machines. This means posting code to create your data using `dput(my_data)` or `data.frame(...)`. It would also be helpful if you posted any code you have tried, e.g. `ggplot(...) + ...`

Comment: In this case it might also be helpful to post an image of your plot with the lines you want drawn on top. Or more description of those lines. It is not exactly clear what your desired output would be.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start by creating the data:

```
df_c <- data.frame(c_n = c(5,9,5,9,10,10,20,20), d13c = c(-5,-10,-10,-5,-15,-25,-15,-25), parameter = c(rep("Algae", 4), rep('Forest Soil', 4)))
```

Now, I'm using `tidyverse` for this:

```
df_c %>% 
  group_by(parameter) %>% 
  summarise(min_cn = min(c_n), 
            max_cn = max(c_n), 
            median_cn = median(c_n),
            min_d13c = min(d13c), 
            max_d13c = max(d13c), 
            median_d13c = median(d13c)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = median_d13c, y = median_cn, group = parameter, color = parameter)) + 
  geom_rect(aes(ymin = min_cn, ymax = max_cn, xmin = min_d13c, xmax = max_d13c, fill = parameter))
```

Using `geom_rect` requires that you calculate the `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin` and `ymax` parameters. `geom_rect` creates a polygon to be used in your `ggplot`. The `median_cn` and `median_d13c` are used as centroids for the rectangles.

[image]